# Android: Commas in Data Entry

Tags: android, numeric

I have users in Europe (Spain/Germany) that are somehow getting commas in their data entry.  With over 100,000 users, only some in Europe are having issues.  None of my American or other European customers are reporting any problems.

One customer that is helping has made sure to enter the number using only a decimal point and I still have the problem.

The field in the Layout is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/xmlPrice"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:numeric="decimal"
    android:maxLength="7"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:hint="0.00" />
```

My class code is as follows:

```
 EditText etPrice ;
 etPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xmlPrice);
 String  v_price = etPrice.getText().toString().trim();

 double d_price ;
 try {
    d_price = Double.parseDouble( v_price );
 } catch(NumberFormatException ex )
 {
    d_price = -1 ;
 }
 DecimalFormat fmtval = new DecimalFormat( "0.00" );

 v_price = fmtval.format( d_price ) ;

 mDbHelper.insertRec( v_id, v_price );
```

When I actually get a copy of their database, sure enough, the data has commas in it.  The dbHelper simply inserts the data with no additional checks, as the code upfront should properly verify correct data entry.

I cannot reproduce the problem in either the Emulator or my 2 test devices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely has to do with the users default locale.  From the documentation of `Locale` there is a subsection labeled [`Be wary of the default locale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale), with a portion that reads:

> For example, if you're formatting integers some locales will use
>   non-ASCII decimal digits. As another example, if you're formatting
>   floating-point numbers some locales will use ',' as the decimal point
>   and '.' for digit grouping.

You create your `DecimalFormat` object using just a pattern, which by the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String%29) says that it uses the users default locale.

You can either force a locale, by using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)` static method (not recommended), or you can provide support for other locales (recommended).